# Как в json с помощью try except проверить значение ключа?

Tags: python, json

У меня есть код:

```
    try:
        sku = product['sku']
        category = product['category']
        name = product['name']
        part = product['part']
        vendor = product['vendor']
        weight = product['weight']
        price = product['price']
        qty = len(product['qty'])

        products_list = {
            "externalcategoryid": category,
            "name": name,
            "briefdescription": part,
            "sku": sku,
            "producer": vendor,
            "weight": weight,
            "price": price,
            "qty": qty
        }
        ready_products.append(products_list)
        print(f'Выгрузка {name} прошла успешно!')
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Мне требуется чтобы при отсутствии данных в одном из выше перечисленных переменных - цикл переходил к следующей итерации.
Пробовал и ValueError и KeyError, но что то не работает, все равно append'ит в массив данные. Помогите пожалуйста.

Соединял два массива с помощью дата фрейма pandas, отсюда и nan.

Comment: Может у Вас есть данные в product с соответсвующим ключем. Но значение = None. Добавьте в свой принт {product} чтобы проверить какие именно данные добавлены

Comment: У меня там NaN, могу ли я в except добавить каким то образовать проверку по этому значению?

Comment: @empty В `Python` нет `NaN`. Предположу, что там `float`

Comment: может быть np.NaN

Comment: с помощью модуля Pandas соединял два массива в один, и образовались nan значения. нужно ли мне их сначала конвертировать в string их? или делать проверку по None?

Comment: nan от pandas и правда float. хм.

Answer (score 2):

Если вы собираетесь обрабатывать исключение возникающее при отсутствии ключа в словаре, то исключение будет: NameError.

```
a = {}
print(a[key])
#https://colab.research.google.com

NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-17f87fc1f0de> in <module>()
      1 a = {}
----> 2 print(a[key])

NameError: name 'key' is not defined
```

Но похоже у вас все ключи на месте. Нужно проверять значение по ключу. А для этого конструкция try - except не нужна.

Comment: Просто хотелось бы поставить одинаковое условие для всех переменных, а не писать для каждого if else, поэтому слышал с помощью try это можно сделать.

Comment: зачем так делать? Есть же обработка NaN... например https://pythonru.com/biblioteki/not-a-number-vse-o-nan-pd-5

Comment: Хм, спасибо, попробую. Просто там я так понимаю dropna() нужно использовать до объединения дата фреймов, с которыми я слабо знаком, но спасибо да, теперь знаю куда двигаться.

Comment: вы главное на копиях пробуйте! Чтобы исходник не дропнуть... )